# Initialize a vector with a callback

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Lets say I have a class:

```
MyType callback(){
 /// randomize here
 .....
 .....
 return randomValue;
}

class MyClass{
private:
  std::vector< MyType > m_vector;

public:
  MyClass( unsigned int size ):m_vector(size, callbackHere? );
};
```

I need to initialize the vector with the values generated by me, how could I do it?
One solution is to make an empty constructor for MyType, this is what I have, but now I would like to replace MyType by pair therefore empty constructor doesn't work.

My callback will return randomized values so in the end I would like to have a vector with some randomized values inside.

Thank You

Comment: What you've written suggests that you want to have the same value for all `size` elements. Is that right? If not, can you give an example of your callback and what you'd like it to initialise your vector with.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Hi joseph no I would like to have a callback which will return random values or values generated by using some logic.

Comment: @AlexTheo what is the advantage of using a callback here? I can't see any?

Comment: @AlexTheo You can just return the whole initialised vector from your callback, not single value.

Comment: @concept3d lets say you need to initialize a vector with the randomized values. If you don't use a callback you will need to do one extra for_each and set the values in, is you have a solution with a callback you directly can initialize your vector..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a custom iterator-like type which

- Generates a new value when pre-/postfix `++` is invoked
- Yields the generated value when it's dereferenced via `operator*`
- Equals some sentry object (the `end` iterator) when you're done generating values

Comment: This is boost iterator generator (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/generator_iterator.htm)

Comment: I did it with boost::transform_iterator + boost::counting_iterator :D

Answer (score 2):

You could have your "callback" return the fully generated vector:

```
std::vector<std::pair<A, B>> callback(unsigned int size){
  std::vector<std::pair<A, B>> v;
  // Build vector
  return v;
}
```

Then you can initialise `m_vector` using its move constructor:

```
MyClass(unsigned int size) : m_vector(callback(size)) { }
```

Comment: You probably want to pass `size` to `callback()`

Comment: So there is no other way to do it? Like using kind of transform_iterator or something like that?

Comment: @AlexTheo You could do it the way Frerich Raabe is suggesting, using the range constructor of `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::generate_n`:

```
std::vector<MyType> v (n);
std::generate_n (v.begin (), n, callback);
```

Variant:

```
std::vector<MyType> v;
std::generate_n (std::back_inserter (v), n, callback);
```

Put this in a static function if you absolutely want it in the constructor initializer, as in Joseph's answer.

Comment: +1 except that this doesn't really "initialize" the vector, it assigns a value to it.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: To really construct the vector, this needs more work: use eg. [boost iterator generator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/generator_iterator.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You could build an initializer_list:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::initializer_list<int> (*callback_function)();
std::initializer_list<int> values() {
    return { 1, 2, 3 };
}

struct X {
    std::vector<int> v;
    X(callback_function f) : v(f()) {};
};

int main() {
    X x(values);
    for(int i: x.v) std::cout << i;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Note: You will loose the size in the constructer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of fun with this. The following code is all C++ 11.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>

class my_random_generator {
        private:
        static std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis;
        public:
        my_random_generator() :
                gen(rd()),
                dis(std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
        {}
        int operator()() {
                return dis(gen);
        }
};

std::random_device my_random_generator::rd;

int main()
{
        std::vector<int> v;
        std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 500, my_random_generator());
        for(auto const &i: v)
                std::cout << i << ',';
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing a function to return the vector already filled is the simplest solution, but if you want to use a custom iterator, here a possible basic implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    for (auto& el : vec)
      os << el << ' ';
    return os;
}

template <typename F >
struct GenerateIterator : std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval<F>()())>::type> {
    using value_type = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval<F>()())>::type;

    GenerateIterator() = default;
    GenerateIterator( F &&f, std::size_t num = 0 ) : num_(num), f_(std::forward<F>(f)) {}

    bool operator!=( GenerateIterator const & o ) { return num_ != o.num_; }
    GenerateIterator& operator++(  ) { --num_; return *this; }

    value_type operator*() { return f_(); }
private:
    std::size_t num_{};
    F f_;
};

template <typename F >
GenerateIterator<F>
MakeGenerateIterator( F &&f, std::size_t num = 0 ) {
    return { std::forward<F>(f), num };
}

int bar() {
    static int val{};
    return 2* val++;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> foo( MakeGenerateIterator(bar, 10), MakeGenerateIterator(bar) );
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: A real input iterator would generate at construction and incrementation to let multiple dereferencing return the same value, but it is fine her, see the @Frerich Raabe answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :D very happy about that:

Combining the boost::transform_iterator and boost::counting_iterator is what I need here

```
   std::pair<float, float> createInput(unsigned int){
        std::pair<float, float> input(utils::createRandom<float>(1), utils::createRandom<float>(1));
        return input;
    }

Neuron ( unsigned int inputsNumber = 1 ) :  m_neuronWeight( utils::createRandom<Var>(1) ), 
                                            m_output(0), 
                                            m_sum(0),
                                            m_inputs(boost::make_transform_iterator( boost::counting_iterator<unsigned int>(0), createInput ),
                                                     boost::make_transform_iterator( boost::counting_iterator<unsigned int>(inputsNumber), createInput )) {
    if ( inputsNumber == 0 ) {
        throw NNException ( "Wrong argument inputsNumber==0", __FILE__, __LINE__ );
    }
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you as well as for me :)